# How to design a XSLT dropdown

Tags: asp.net, forms, xslt

How to design a dropdown on XSLT? I need a dropdown with four values
option 1
option 2
option 3
option 4

I have the following on the XSLT

```
<div>
 <select>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
 </select> 
</div>
```

I wanted to pass the selected value from the dropdown to the asp.net

Comment: The code you showed us is HTML. (Maybe you have it in your XSLT too.) The question of how to pass the selected value from the dropdown to a server page is a question of your HTML/javascript, and your ASP page, nothing to do with XSLT. Once you have the HTML/javascript designed, we can help you with the XSLT if you need it. If you're not going to say anything about your input XML, you don't need help with XSLT, and you should change your question title and tags. Otherwise the question will likely be closed.

Comment: This is present inside the XSLT. I have to work on making the selectedindexchanged work. I am not able to do this as of now.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT has nothing to do with "designing a dropdown". It is an XML-based language to transform an input XML tree into some other form of output.  XSLT has no concept of a "dropdown", that would be in whatever web or UI system you're using.

Answer (score 0):

1. First design the output, in other words, decide specifically what HTML you want to produce.
2. Then determine the input XML and figure out what parts of it need to be reflected in the output dropdown.

If you can show us those two things, we can help you figure out what sort of XSLT to use.

FYI there is an example [here](http://www.knebel.net/index.php?req=view_item&id=127) of an XSLT template for generating an OPTION/SELECT. You could try that and let us know if you need help figuring out how to use it.